# R Markdown does not print table of contents

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am using R 3.6.0 and RStudio 1.2.1335 (newest versions) on my Windows 10 PC and I am not able to print the Table of Contents on my beamer presentation using RMarkdown. This problem started a few days ago and I cannot seem to find the problem. My code works perfectly on RStudio Cloud. However, when I try to run the same code on my installed RStudio version, I don't get any error messages, but the TOC page is blank. I am sure I am correctly creating section titles using only one #, however, the system does not seem to get they are sections.

I tried everything, reinstalling R and RStudio, even with previous versions, reinstalling MikTex, uninstalling some PC updates, even uninstalling programs I installed recently to see if there were any conflict. None of them worked. Again, my code prints the TOC perfectly on RStudio Cloud, so the problem is on my PC.

````
---
title: "Test"
author: "Guillermo"
date: "21/5/2019"
output: beamer_presentation
toc: true
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

# R Markdown

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown presentation. Markdown is a simple 
formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word 
documents. For more details on using R Markdown see 
<http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be 
generated that includes both content as well as the output 
of any embedded R code chunks within the document.
````

I don't receive any error message. It's driving me crazy.

Comment: Same problem here. Nothing to offer except I share your pain.